# How Apply color to xlHairline

Tags: vba, excel

I've written a small macro that formats an excel sheet and exports it to a PDF.

I am sorting out the look&feel of the PDF and I would like to modify the borders.

I have modified the borders the way I wanted to but I would like to try it out with a **XLBorderWeight** of type **xlHairline**.

The problem is that i would like to apply a color to my **xlHairline**. It comes out on my PDF in **black** instead of my **ColorIndex(3)** (it's red)

All other **XLBorderWeight** get colored correctly.

```
With Selection.FormatConditions(1)
    With .Font
        .ColorIndex = 3
    End With
    With .Borders
        .ColorIndex = 3
        .Weight = xlHairline
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    End With
End With
```

I have tried it also outside of **Conditional Formating** and the same issue appears.

I have searched for the past 2 hours to see if it is possible or not to color an **xlHairline** but with no answer.

Anyone here has an idea on how to solve this?

**EDIT:**

Here is a visual of it when applied using .Borders (conditionnal formatting) or .Borders(xlBorderIndex Enumeration)

Here the edge is **xlHairline red** while the inside is **xlThin white**

Result is the same if I use my script or Vityata's answer

[image: Black Hairline]

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example:

```
Sub TestMe()

    With Selection
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlHairline
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlHairline
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlHairline
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlHairline

        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).ColorIndex = 3
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).ColorIndex = 3
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).ColorIndex = 3
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).ColorIndex = 3
    End With

End Sub
```

In your code, if you write `With .Borders(xlEdgeLeft)` then it would work quite ok, but only for the left border. Then you have to think of a way to cover all the 4 Edges, like in example:

Comment: Out of my Conditional Formating function, i have the exact same code as you wrote and the output is the same : black hairline. Check my Edit for an image